# How to login with with cURL when username or password include the "@" character?

Tags: php, php-curl

```
$cSession   = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://hai:hai@7@redmine.org/users/current.json");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$userDetail = curl_exec($cSession);
```

The character after the '@' in the password is taken as the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put your credentials in the URL string. Set them like this:

```
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_URL,"http://redmine.org/user/current.json");
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) the username and password.  That should solve the problem.

```
$user = 'hai';
$pass = 'hai@7';

$creds = urlencode($user) . ':' . urlencode($pass)

// result hai:hai%407
```

Then you can pass that `$creds` string in the URL, or as `CURLOPW_USERPWD`.

Comment: It should if it follows the HTTP protocol specs.